# Multidimensional Mutable Dictionary - Objective C

Tags: ios, dictionary, multidimensional-array

i work to a IOS project and i have a problem.
I need to save a date structure like this:

```
array(
'0'=>array(
    0=>array('key'=>'value','key2'=>'value2'),
    1=>array('key'=>'value','key2'=>'value2'),
    3=>array('key'=>'value','key2'=>'value2')
    ),
'1'=>
    array(
    0=>array('key'=>'value','key2'=>'value2'),
    1=>array('key'=>'value','key2'=>'value2'),
    3=>array('key'=>'value','key2'=>'value2')
    )
)
```

What is the best practice?

I'll try to use Mutable Dictionary, but i'm doing something wrong because the method, save only the last entries.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
_dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];



 [self costruiciMenuConIdentificatore:@"immagineTop" Testo:@"Immagine" Segue:@"immagine" Sezione:@"0" Locale:@"1"];
    [self costruiciMenuConIdentificatore:@"informazioni" Testo:@"Informazioni" Segue:@"infoHome" Sezione:@"0" Locale:@"1"];
    [self costruiciMenuConIdentificatore:@"news" Testo:@"News" Segue:@"newsHome" Sezione:@"0" Locale:@"1"];
    [self costruiciMenuConIdentificatore:@"prenota" Testo:@"Prenota" Segue:@"prenotaHome" Sezione:@"0" Locale:@"1"];
    [self costruiciMenuConIdentificatore:@"foto" Testo:@"Foto" Segue:@"fotoHome" Sezione:@"0" Locale:@"1"];
    [self costruiciMenuConIdentificatore:@"mappa" Testo:@"Mappa" Segue:@"mappaHome" Sezione:@"0" Locale:@"1"];
    [self costruiciMenuConIdentificatore:@"immagineTop" Testo:@"Immagine" Segue:@"immagine" Sezione:@"1" Locale:@"1"];
    [self costruiciMenuConIdentificatore:@"informazioni" Testo:@"Informazioni" Segue:@"infoHome" Sezione:@"1" Locale:@"1"];
    [self costruiciMenuConIdentificatore:@"news" Testo:@"News" Segue:@"newsHome" Sezione:@"1" Locale:@"1"];
    [self costruiciMenuConIdentificatore:@"prenota" Testo:@"Prenota" Segue:@"prenotaHome" Sezione:@"1" Locale:@"1"];
    [self costruiciMenuConIdentificatore:@"foto" Testo:@"Foto" Segue:@"fotoHome" Sezione:@"1" Locale:@"1"];
    [self costruiciMenuConIdentificatore:@"mappa" Testo:@"Mappa" Segue:@"mappaHome" Sezione:@"1" Locale:@"1"];
    NSLog(@"%@",_dictionary);
    }

    //metodo che costruisce il menu
    - (void)costruiciMenuConIdentificatore:(NSString*)identificatore Testo:(NSString*)testo    Segue:(NSString*)segue Sezione:(NSString*) sezione Locale:(NSString*) locale
    {
    NSInteger code;
    NSMutableDictionary *firstOne = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [firstOne setObject:identificatore forKey:@"identifier"];
    [firstOne setObject:testo forKey:@"testo"];
    [firstOne setObject:segue forKey:@"segue"];
    [firstOne setObject:sezione forKey:@"sezione"];
    [firstOne setObject:locale forKey:@"locale"];


    if ([sezione isEqual:@"1"])
    {
        code=0;
    }
    else
    {
        code=1;
    }

    [_dictionary  setObject:firstOne forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:code]];
   }
```

Where i make mistakes?

Comment: If a NSDictionnary has already a object with key `0`, when you'll had an object with key `0`, it will replace the previous object with key `0` with the new one.

Comment: Is possibile to create an array of dictionary ?

Comment: Also, try to name your methods starting (each parameters) with a lowercase, like this: `-(void)costruiciMenuConIdentificatore:(NSString*)identificatore testo:(NSString*)testo segue:(NSString*)segue sezione:(NSString*)sezione locale:(NSString*)locale`

Comment: And yes, it's possible to create an array of dictionary.

Comment: I'll make this change, but the problem is the same.